# How to store byte array in Array list android?

Tags: android, arrays

I am not getting the way to store byte[] in array list.
Encoding/Decoding using string is not working properly.

Please Help.

Comment: edit the question with the code so far, if you are not looking for downvotes!

Comment: @oblivion I need the answer, not votes. Stuck!!..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
List<Byte> array = new ArrayList<Byte>();
array.add((byte)1);
array.add((byte)3);
//etc..
Byte[] arrayBytes = array.toArray(new Byte[array.size()]);
byte[] byteArray = Bytes.toArray(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ByteArrayList {
  private List<Byte> bytesList;

  public ByteArrayList() {
    bytesList = new ArrayList<Byte>();
  }

  public void add(byte[] bytes) {
    add(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
  }

  public void add(byte[] bytes, int offset, int length) {
    for (int i = offset; i < (offset + length); i++) {
      bytesList.add(bytes[i]);
    }
  }

  public byte[] getArray() {
    byte[] bytes = new byte[bytesList.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < bytesList.size(); i++) {
      bytes[i] = bytesList.get(i);
    }

    return bytes;
  }
}
```